# Appium's startActivity() method doesn't work... throws WebDriverException: unknown error

Tags: appium, start-activity

As part of practice I'm trying to switch app activities with **AndroidDriver** and `startActivity()` method. When I run the Test, I see on my phone that required application launches but then it crashes and I get the following Exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error (An unknown
> server-side error occurred. status='false'. Failed to complete
> internal method: 'startActivity args:
> [com.shivgadhia.android.ukMortgageCalc,
> com.shivgadhia.android.ukMortgageCalc.MainActivity,
> com.shivgadhia.android.ukMortgageCalc,
> com.shivgadhia.android.ukMortgageCalc.MainActivity, null, null, null,
> null, true, 10000]', details: Failed to start activity . wait for
> com.shivgadhia.android.ukMortgageCalc/.MainActivity failed after
> timeout)  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
> information)

**my code is:**

```
protected AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "LMG710EM210b0b9a");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.example.android.apis");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".ApiDemos");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
}

@Test 
public void Test03_startActivity(){
    driver.tap(1, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Views']")),500);
    driver.startActivity("com.shivgadhia.android.ukMortgageCalc",".MainActivity");
    driver.tap(1, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Rate']")),500);
}
```

The last code line is not executed and the Test Fails with above mentioned exception. Searched the web and couldn't find any solution. What could be the problem?

Comment: One reason for that can be that the appium server doesn't have the latest version. My appium server was on version 1.X and when I upgraded it to 2.X it worked (note, I used Browserstack and had to change the version there explicitly to V2 as well)

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to start any activity on your device that easy.
Before doing it via Appium, give it a try via adb:

```
am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

If it doesn't work, it won't work with Appium as well.

I also suggest checking [docs](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup/) to troubleshoot the issue